# How to correctly terminate a TTL line between two ICs?

Tags: pcb-design, impedance-matching, ttl, termination

I am designing a circuit to convert a 5ns ECL signal to an LVTTL signal of >10ns.  The SY100ELT25 is used to convert the ECL to 5V TTL which is then fed into the SN74LVC1G123 to further reduce the voltage to LVTTL and stretch the pulse.

The two chips will be separated by a few millimetres.

My question is, should there be any termination resistors on the line between the two ICs? i.e. Q to B

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXGEjX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: As it's point to point, there won't be any harm in using a series termination at the output of the SY100, if you have room for it. But at 'a few mm', it's unlikely to be necessary

Comment: I would be very, very cautious about feeding a nominally 5 volt TTL signal into a 3.3 LVTTL chip. Depending on the actual output of the ELT25,  it may attempt to drive the 3.3 volt line. It might well work, but you should test the bejeezus out of it. Otherwise, you don't need termination for a few millimeters of trace length. Long ago I used to work with ECL, and the rule was that termination resistors could be up to an inch away from the nominal termination point.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast LVC inputs are overvoltage tolerant.

Comment: Yes, the recommended operating conditions of the SN74LVC1G123 explicitly says it can accept an input voltage between 0-5.5V and can be used as a voltage translator.